# rankMatrix function not found in R

Tags: r, matrix, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to find the rank of a matrix in R using `rankMatrix(A)`.
I get the error :

```
Error: could not find function "rankMatrix"
```

Other functions/operations from the `Matrix` package (matrix transpose `t()`, `solve()`, matrix multiplication `%*%`) work just fine. I don't know what to make of this error.

Comment: Reinstall pkg:Matrix. And if your version of R is older than 2.15.3 then please update before doing so. I'm not sure when the last version where the rankMatrix was modified but the Changelog suggests to me that it was around Matrix_1.0-2.tar.gz.

Comment: Those other operations are part of base R, not from pkg:Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the "Matrix" library inorder to use rankMatrix.

```
library(Matrix)
rankMatrix(A)
```

Here, see the documentation:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/rankMatrix.html

Comment: Importing the library got this working. I'm surprised `transpose` and `solve` worked without the explicit import while `rankMatrix` did not. I tried it in a fresh R environment too and found the same behaviour. I wonder why...

Comment: ?transpose()
     Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
     no methods for ‘transpose’ and no documentation for it as a  function

Which function you used? I am unable to find 'transpose' in Matrix package. I do transpose simply by using t(A); t is from "base" library itself